# When sorted-ing a dictionary for values, what determines what order the keys go in when there are multiple keys with the same value?

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I'm tracking the score in a paper/scissors/rock game, and the player's used both paper and rock twice, giving the dict tracking the moves `{'rock': 2, 'paper': 2, 'scissors': 0}` I call `print(sorted(dict, key=dict.get, reverse=True))`, returning the list `['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']`. Why is it in this order and not `['paper', 'rock', 'scissors']`?

Comment: You are sorting by value so what order do you expect?

Comment: Though you are sorting by value, in case of a tie, `sorted` will do a stable sort. This means whatever dictionary item is "first" will be first in the produced list. However, a Python dictionary isn't supposed to have a concept of order. There are a lot of questions on Stack Overflow that address the concept (or lack thereof) of dictionary order.

Comment: What you want is `sorted(d, key=lambda x:[-d[x], x])`, sort by negating the value and break ties with the key name.